Way of defining families of proper classes in class theory.
The background theory is Morse-Kelley (or NBG).
(for usual relation "is element" we use normal $\in$)
Assume F to be any relation.(A class of certain ordered pairs.)
Now, let's interpret it as a family of proper classes in the following way:
Define:
$$(P\mbox{ IN }F) \iff (\exists (i\mbox{ set}): \bigcup F[\{i\}]=P)$$
Define:
$$(\mbox{UNION }F) := \bigcup\mbox{ran}(F)$$
etc.
Does such encoding have a name? Where it is possible to read about it?
Example of use of it:
Define(here, for the lemma):
$$F:=\{(x,\{y\})|(x\mbox{ any})\land(y \in x)\} \cup \{(\emptyset,\emptyset)\}$$
(it is almost $s[E^{-1}]$, so $\bigcup F[\{i\}] = \bigcup s[E^{-1}[\{i\}]]=E^{-1}[\{i\}]=\bigcup\{i\}=i$ for any set i. Remark: it's better to use $\{b|(a,b)\in G\}$ than $G[\{a\}]$), since the former is treats case when a is a proper set more adequately/naturally (it returns the empty set) than the latter(it returns the [set-]range of G).
Def. Class-function s maps x to {x}.
s={(x,{x})| x any}
lemma1:$\bigcup (s[A]) = A$. (monadic property)
Lemma2: (Q IN F) $\iff$ (Q set).
Proof.

Q IN F. <=> exists (i set): $\bigcup$F[{i}]=Q.
if i not in dom F then $\bigcup$F[{i}] = {}, so Q={}, obviously a set.\
if i in dom F. then  $\bigcup$F[{i}] = $\bigcup$s[E^(-1)[{i}]]=E^(-1)[{i}]=union({i})=i. i is in dom F, so i is a set. So {i} is a set. Therefore F[{i}] is a set. We have F[{i}]=Q, so Q is a set.
Q set. i:=Q. So (i set). So {i} is defined and {i} is a set. (via simple definition of {-}). So (i in {i}). Also ({i},{i}) is a set. So ({i},{i}) is in {(x,{y})|x any, y in x} via x:={i}, y:=i.

QED
Since we in fact "split the value into singletones"(or empty set, for 1 case when f(x)={}), then the following definition works both for both cases: for function F given as graph(set of pairs, functional relation), and for function F given as family (something like {(x,{y})|...}).
Def. Value of a family F at x. $$F(x)=\bigcup \{b|(x,b)\in F\}$$
It allows to "collect" some proper classes. (make pairs of them, also tuples)
It seems like is not possible to define a "class of all classes" via this definition.
(otherwise it would be $\forall P(\exists (i\mbox{ set}): \bigcup F[\{i\}]=P)$. BTW: How to derive a Russel-like paradox out of this?)
There are certainly some axioms which are true about such constructions.(Would such relation create something like ZFC?) But i don't know them, so instead of re-proving everything, asking here for a reference/explanation/ideas.
I would like to know, what theory such relation leads to.
Thanks in advance!
p.s. some definitions:


I'm not sure this will help with your class-theory applications, but the construction you are describing is entirely standard in model theory, under the name  "definable family of definable sets".

@AlexKruckman could you please share your favorite source on this topic with this definition? It's hard to navigate to it properly without the name of the book...
